# redirecting current runing python process' stdout

Tags: python, stdout, io-redirection

I have python code that runs C code that spams stdout and stderr.

I want to suppress that stdout and stderr, without being able to modify the C code. As pseudocode, roughly:

```py
def external_api_I_cant_control():
    C code that outputs to stdout & stderr # this is not a subprocess 
                                           # call which I can redirect
                                           # its stdout & stderr. Rather,
                                           # it's a wrapper for it so there
                                           # is nothing I can do to control its
                                           # FD

def do_stuff():
    external_api_I_cant_control()
```

My code is being run using `python bla.py` and so, I can redirect `stderr` using `python bla.py 2>/dev/null`, however this does not fix my problem, as some of the spam is to `stdout` and I can't redirect `stdout` - because I need some of it.

Is it possible to do, from within my code, the equivalent of shell stdout redirection?

I tried so far:

1. `contextlib.redirect_stdout`
2. replacing `sys.stdout` and `sys.__stdout__` with `open(os.devnull, 'w')`

My desired outcome would be the equivalent of splitting my `bla.py` into 3 and running it like this:

```sh
python bla0.output.is.legit.py
python bla1.output.should.be.disregarded.py &> /dev/null
python bla2.output.is.legit.again.py
```

What would be the way to achieve this?

Comment: `os.dup2()` is your friend. Shouldn't be that hard to write an equivalent to `contextlib.redirect_stdout` that uses it.

Comment: How are you running the subprocess? Are you using the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)?

Comment: (saying *"`subprocess` call I can't control"*, with `subprocess` code-formatted, implies it's a Python `subprocess` library use, not just an actual subprocess made by C code `fork()`ing and `exec()`ing. If you mean the latter, don't code-format it to avoid the incorrect implication)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I do mean the latter. How would you suggest I format my code to make it clearer?

Comment: Just say "a subprocess", not "a `subprocess`". When you say `subprocess`, that means `subprocess` is code, and as Python code, that means a use of the standard-library `subprocess` module.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy how to use `dup2`? This would duplicate my stdout, not remove it, no?

Comment: You can use `dup2()` to copy a file descriptor _over another FD that already exists_ -- so you can copy something new/different _over_ stdout or stderr to replace it. This is how redirection works in C (and thus how shells implement it under-the-hood).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for `os.dup2()`. The code you want consists of three stages:

- Backing up the original stdout and stderr
- Replacing stdout and stderr with file handles pointing at `/dev/null`
- Restoring the backups (after running the code you want).

---

```py
# create a backup of stdout and stderr
orig_stdout_fd = os.dup(1)
orig_stderr_fd = os.dup(2)

# make the original stdout and stderr point to /dev/null
devnull = open('/dev/null', 'r+')
os.dup2(devnull.fileno(), 1)
os.dup2(devnull.fileno(), 2)

# run your C code here
os.write(1, b"This would normally go to stdout\n")

# put the originals back
os.dup2(orig_stdout_fd, 1)
os.dup2(orig_stderr_fd, 2)
os.close(orig_stdout_fd)
os.close(orig_stderr_fd)
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks! It seems weird to me that this is not done by `contextlib`

Comment: also, why do you close the original FD in the end?

Comment: @CIsForCookies, file descriptors are a limited resource. Granted, the number available is not all that small on modern operating systems, but that's no excuse for writing code that leaks them; call that in a loop and one will eventually run out.